# Nearby cycle complex of a scheme over a DVR with finite number of singularities

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory, derived-functors, etale-cohomology, derived-categories

Let $R$ be a DVR and $S = \mathrm{Spec}(R)$ with closed point $s$ and generic point $\eta$. Let $X\to S$ be a scheme over $S$, and denote by $X_s$ and $X_{\eta}$ the special and generic fibers. We assume that there exists a finite number of closed points $x_1,\ldots ,x_n \in X_s$ such that the open subscheme $U := X \setminus \{x_1,\ldots,x_n\}$ is smooth over $S$.

Let $\ell$ be a prime number different from the residual characteristic of $R$. Let $\Lambda := \mathbb Z_{\ell}/ \ell^k\mathbb Z_{\ell}$ where $k\geq 1$. Consider the derived nearby cycle functor $\mathrm R\Psi_{\eta}$ relative to $X$.

Is it true that $\mathrm R^0\Psi_{\eta}\Lambda \simeq \Lambda$ and $\mathrm R^q\Psi_{\eta}\Lambda$ for $q\geq 1$ is skyscraper concentrated in the singular points $x_1,\ldots ,x_n$?

Does this generalize to $\mathrm R\Psi_{\eta}K$ for $K \in D^+(X_{\eta},\Lambda)$ any bounded-below complex of $\Lambda$-adic sheaves on $X_{\eta}$?

Comment: For the first question, yes if $X_s$ is of dimension greater or equal to 1. If $X_s$ is of dimension $0$, then $R^0\Psi_\eta\Lambda$ might be of rank greater than 1 (and might be a non trivial representation of $\operatorname{Gal}(\overline{\eta}/\eta)$). For the generalization, you need to be more precise. What kind of generalization are you expecting ?

Comment: @Roland Thank you very much for your comment! In the case I'm interested in, $X_s$ does have positive dimension, so we may add this assumption. I understand why the $\mathrm R^q \Psi_{\eta}\Lambda$ for positive $q$ are skyscraper considering the smooth base change theorem applied to the smooth locus $U$ of $X$. However, I fail to see the argument regarding $\mathrm R^0\Psi_{\eta}\Lambda$. Would you mind elaborating a little bit more here? As for the "generalization", it was a naive question to check whether a more general formula is known or not. We may disregard it for now.

Comment: Let me just write down my thoughts for $\mathrm R^0\Psi_{\eta}\Lambda$. We have a natural morphism $\Lambda \to \mathrm R\Psi_{\eta}\Lambda$, inducing a map $\Lambda \to \mathrm R^0\Psi_{\eta}\Lambda$. By smooth base change, this map is an isomorphism on stalks at any point $x$ in the smooth locus of $X_s$. The sheaf $\mathrm R^0\Psi_{\eta}\Lambda$ is constructible, so locally constant on a stratification of $X_s$. So $\mathrm R^0\Psi_{\eta}\Lambda$ is constant on an étale neighborhood of any singular point inside the stratum to which they belong. [...]

Comment: Evaluating at a point of these étale neighborhoods different from the singular points (which we may do since $\dim X_s > 0$), we may find out that $\Lambda \to \mathrm R^0\Psi_{\eta}\Lambda$ is an isomorphism at the singular points as well. Does this sounds right?

Comment: The argument is not enough : the stratum of $x$ may very well be $\{x\}$ itself and there would be no other point to evaluate $R^0\Psi_\eta\Lambda$. What you need to prove is that if $U$ is an etale neighborhood of $x$ in $X$, then $U_\eta$ is connected. But now I am confused because I don't think it is true without additional hypotheses and I believe I can give a counter example.

Comment: @Roland Thank you again for pointing out the case where $\{x\}$ itself is a stratum, I missed it entirely. About your statement regarding all étale neighborhoods of $x$ in $X$ having connected generic fibers, how would this imply that $(\mathrm R^0\Psi_{\eta}\Lambda)_x \simeq \Lambda$?

Comment: You have an isomorphism $H^p(X_s,R\Psi_\eta\Lambda)=H^p(X_\overline{\eta},\Lambda)$ if $X$ is flat and proper (which I assumed in my previous comments, otherwise there is no hope for such an isomorphism). Use this to prove that $(R^0\Psi_\eta\Lambda)_x=\varinjlim H^0(U_{\overline{\eta}},\Lambda)$ where the limits is over the neighborhood $U$ of $x$ in $U$.

Comment: @Roland Thank you very much, it's very clear! Your comments allowed me to get some valuable insight into my problem.